# Troubles with regexp in R: Match word surrounded by whitespace or start/end of string

Tags: r, regex, stringi

I want to count the number of words from a dictionary that appear in a string if it is surrounded by whitespace or it is at the start or end of the string.

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13225891/4462566) answer like this:

```
library(stringi)

testStr <- c("dutch dutch brown", "brown ", "AAdutch", "dutchAA", "AAbrown",
             "brownAA", "hello")
stri_count_regex(testStr, "(^|\\s+)dutch|brown(\\s+|$)")
```

Which returns `3 1 0 1 1 0 0`, but I'm expecting `3 1 0 0 0 0 0`. So the problem is that it also counts `"dutchAA"` and `"AAbrown"` which I don't want.

I'm a bit puzzled about this, as this regular expression works fine when I run it on [RegExr](http://regexr.com/).

Comment: maybe `stri_count_regex(testStr, "\\b(dutch|brown)\\b")` not sure of the difference, can you post the link to the regextr you used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following *regex* :

```
(?:\b|\s+)(?:dutch|brown)(?:\s+|\b)
```

**[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9zbX9w/1)**

**r**

```
library(stringi)

testStr <- c("dutch dutch brown", "brown ", "AAdutch", "dutchAA", "AAbrown",
             "brownAA", "hello")
stri_count_regex(testStr, "(?:\\b|\\s+)(?:dutch|brown)(?:\\s+|\\b)")  # 3 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Just a little additional context: `(?:pattern)` is a "[non-capturing group](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3513858/143319)", and `\\b` is a word boundary - it matches on the start or end of a word without actually matching any characters from the word.

Comment: What's the motivation for the non-capturing groups here, anyway?